# How to update an existing Conda environment with a .yml file

Tags: python, django, anaconda, conda

How can a pre-existing conda environment be updated with another .yml file. This is extremely helpful when working on projects that have multiple requirement files, i.e. `base.yml, local.yml, production.yml`, etc.

For example, below is a `base.yml` file has conda-forge, conda, and pip packages:

base.yml

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - django=1.10.5
  - pip:
    - django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
```

The actual environment is created with:
`conda env create -f base.yml`.

Later on, additional packages need to be added to `base.yml`. Another file, say `local.yml`, needs to import those updates.

Previous attempts to accomplish this include:

creating a `local.yml` file with an import definition:

```
channels:

dependencies:
  - pip:
    - boto3==1.4.4
imports:
  - requirements/base.
```

And then run the command:
`conda install -f local.yml`.

This does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible to update the currently activated environment?? I just tried this but the update went to the environment named in the yml file.

Comment: this might be useful to start from scratch: `conda env create -f ~/CoqGym/coq_gym.yml` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54492671/how-to-install-list-of-python-libraries-using-yml-file-without-making-new-enviro)

Answer (score 574, accepted):

Try using [conda env update](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html):

```
conda activate myenv
conda env update --file local.yml --prune
```

`--prune` uninstalls dependencies which were removed from `local.yml`, as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54825300/2261298) by @Blink.

*Attention:* if there is a `name` tag with a name other than that of your environment in `local.yml`, the command above will create a new environment with that name. To avoid this, use (thanks @NumesSanguis):

```
conda env update --name myenv --file local.yml --prune
```

See [Updating an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=prune#updating-an-environment) in Conda User Guide.

Comment: You don't need the equals sign between `-f` and `file.yml`. Removing the equals sign will make tab completion work on the `.yml` filename.

Comment: Add `--name env_name` to ignore any `name: foo` tag in `local.yml`. Also prevents the need to activate myenv first. Full command: `conda env update --name env_name --file local.yml`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525593/3399066 's comment

Comment: In the most recent conda version I think we use "conda activate myenv" instead of "source activate myenv"

Comment: Is there any way, we can pass an argument where this command will just update available libraries in .yml files, which will ensure that error is not thrown when any of the library listed is not available?

Comment: make sure that the YAML file has no `name` parameter, otherwise it **creates** with this **update** command

Comment: why aren't you passing the `--prune` flag? as in `conda env update -f local.yml --prune`?

Comment: @DimaLituiev can you clarify what you mean with `otherwise it creates with this update command`? what is the issue if the name is there already? also, will the prefix word at the bottom create an issue?

Comment: FYI `conda env update --file local.yml --prune` will generate an environment with the name specified in the .yml (i.e., `name: <some_name>`) so activating your destination environment does nothing

Comment: Is that doable without using conda? Just with regular pip/virtualenv?

Comment: if the env file includes `name: myenv`, is it necessary to `conda activate myenv` or provide `--name myenv`?

Answer (score 82):

The suggested answer is partially correct. You'll need to add the **--prune** option to also uninstall packages that were removed from the environment.yml. 
Correct command:

```
conda env update -f local.yml --prune
```

Comment: Even the **--prune** flag is not enough to remove pip installed dependencies...

Comment: True. I think it will remove the conda dependencies but not the ones listed under pip

Comment: Is there any way, we can pass an argument where this command will just update available libraries in .yml files, which will ensure that error is not thrown when any of the library listed is not available?

Comment: would there be a problem if my `requirements.yml` file has a `name:` at the top?

Answer (score 36):

alkamid's answer is on the right lines, but I have found that Conda fails to install new dependencies if the environment is already active. Deactivating the environment first resolves this:

```sh
source deactivate;
conda env update -f whatever.yml;
source activate my_environment_name; # Must be AFTER the conda env update line!
```

Comment: How does conda know which env to update if it's not the currently active one?

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger you can specify it explicitly with `-n <environment name>`, but by default it seems to work with the expected environment (maybe the most recently active, or just a default environment choice)

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger The name of the environment is specified in the YAML file if it has been exported by conda.

Comment: I thought the old point of this question is to update a different environment to the one specified in the yaml file.

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger the yaml file includes the environment name

Answer (score 1):

Recently Conda introduced the option to [stack environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#nested-activation), which should solve this problem.