# Is it possible to import dependencies from a CONDA environment.yml into my current environment?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I realise I can create a new environment from a yml with `conda env create -f environment.yml` (from [conda docs](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html)).

However in my case, I have an environment already setup with a ton of things installed and setup just the way I like and need it. Now I'd like to install a new package which has a [bunch of dependencies](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daavoo/pyntcloud/master/env.yml). From what I can see there are no conflicts with my current env. Is it possible to somehow import this yml into my current environment? I couldn't find any info on this on the docs or the web (they all point back to creating a new env from the yml).

I realise I can export my current environment as a yml, do a merge with the new yml, and then create a new environment with the merged file, but that seems a bit convoluted for something which I think would be a relatively common request.

Comment: I think the reason for this is that the dependencies of a package should be automatically handled when you install it - you shouldn't need an `environment.yml` to manage the dependencies of a single package. I think if you have a particular use case, merging is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do an environment update like this by following the instructions here: 
[How to update an existing Conda environment with a .yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352841/how-to-update-an-existing-conda-environment-with-a-yml-file/46114295#46114295)

I did have to deactivate the environment to update the dependencies as per Dave's comment.