# Install packages into existing conda environment specified in environment.yml

Tags: anaconda, conda, development-environment

I have anaconda environment called *'juldou_learning'*.

I downloaded from Git a project with **environment.yml** inside.

I don't want to create new environment with environment.yml like:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

but, only install packages to juldou_learning which are present in environment.yml file.

following does not work:

```
(juldou_learning) MBPuzivlaJulius:juldou_learning juldou$ conda install --file environment.yml 

CondaValueError: could not parse 'name: juldou_learning' in: environment.yml
```

Comment: Does `conda install --file environment.yml` work? https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html You might need to activate your environment first.

Comment: What about `conda env update --file environment.yml` https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-update.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an existing Conda environment with a .yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352841/how-to-update-an-existing-conda-environment-with-a-yml-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`env` command](https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-update.html)

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

You may need to activate the environment into which the packages are going to be installed first.

Comment: Unfortunately if you have an environment name in `environment.yml` the update/install will  happen to that named environment. But you can easily fix that with `conda env update --name env_name --file environment.yml`

Answer (score 12):

Like @darthbith said, use `conda-env update`, but don't forget to name the environment you want to install the packages into. If the `environment.yml` file contains an environment name, your packages will get installed there, regardless of which environment is currently activated. Here's how to name the target environment name:

```
conda env update --name environment_name --file environment.yml
```

Of course there are short argument names for `--name` and `--file`. To install the `environment.yml` packages in my `base` conda environment (the one that's activated if you haven't activated any others) I had to:

```
conda env update -n base -f environment.yml
```