# Add full anaconda package list to existing conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I know how to add single packages and I know that the `conda create` command supports adding a new environment with all anaconda packages installed.

But how can I add all anaconda packages to an existing environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install packages into existing conda environment specified in environment.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510430/install-packages-into-existing-conda-environment-specified-in-environment-yml)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem as following:

1. Create a helper env with anaconda: `conda create -n env_name anaconda`
2. Activate that env `conda activate env_name`
3. Export packages into specification file: `conda list --explicit > spec-file.txt`
4. Activate the target environment: `activate target_env_name`
5. Import that specification file: `conda install --file spec-file.txt`