# How to import someone else's conda environment with all of the dependencies

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

I'm trying to follow along with [this guide](https://github.com/Spandan-Madan/DeepLearningProject) for machine learning. The github post provides a .yml file that I'm supposed to use to make a conda environment, but every time I try `conda env create -f deeplearningproject_environment.yml` it says I'm missing all of the prerequisites, including things I know I have installed like python and pip. My friends tell me that I have to create an environment before I put the dependencies in, but conda won't let me create the environment without having the dependencies, so I'm stuck. Here's my error:

```
    ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - enum34==1.1.6=py27_0
  - python-dateutil==2.6.0=py27_0
  - readline==6.2=2
  - six==1.10.0=py27_0
  - wheel==0.29.0=py27_0
  - singledispatch==3.4.0.3=py27_0
  - jupyter==1.0.0=py27_0
  - setuptools==27.2.0=py27_0
  - pip==9.0.1=py27_1
  - get_terminal_size==1.0.0=py27_0
  - zlib==1.2.8=3
  - scandir==1.5=py27_0
  - python==2.7.13=0
  - gensim==2.2.0=np112py27_0
  - openssl==1.0.2l=0
  - pyzmq==16.0.2=py27_0
  - decorator==4.0.11=py27_0
  - ssl_match_hostname==3.4.0.2=py27_1
  - ptyprocess==0.5.1=py27_0
  - backports_abc==0.5=py27_0
  - pygments==2.2.0=py27_0
  - traitlets==4.3.2=py27_0
  - ipykernel==4.6.1=py27_0
  - scipy==0.19.1=np112py27_0
  - pexpect==4.2.1=py27_0
  - pathlib2==2.2.1=py27_0
  - backports==1.0=py27_0
  - sqlite==3.13.0=0
  - tk==8.5.18=0
  - path.py==10.3.1=py27_0
  - ipython==5.3.0=py27_0
  - torchvision==0.1.8=py27_0
  - pickleshare==0.7.4=py27_0
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.14=py27_0
  - tornado==4.5.1=py27_0
  - simplegeneric==0.8.1=py27_1
  - numpy==1.12.1=py27_0
```

And here's a list of the dependencies:

```
     backports=1.0=py27_0
- backports_abc=0.5=py27_0
- decorator=4.0.11=py27_0
- enum34=1.1.6=py27_0
- gensim=2.2.0=np112py27_0
- get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py27_0
- ipykernel=4.6.1=py27_0
- ipython=5.3.0=py27_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py27_0
- jupyter=1.0.0=py27_0
- jupyter_client=5.2.3=py27_0
- jupyter_core=4.4.0=py27_0
- numpy==1.12.1=py27_0
- openssl=1.0.2l=0
- path.py=10.3.1=py27_0
- pathlib2=2.2.1=py27_0
- pexpect=4.2.1=py27_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py27_0
- pip=9.0.1=py27_1
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.14=py27_0
- ptyprocess=0.5.1=py27_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py27_0
- python=2.7.13=0
- python-dateutil=2.6.0=py27_0
- pyzmq=16.0.2=py27_0
- readline=6.2=2
- scandir=1.5=py27_0
- scipy==0.19.1=np112py27_0
- setuptools=27.2.0=py27_0
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py27_1
- singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py27_0
- six=1.10.0=py27_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- ssl_match_hostname=3.4.0.2=py27_1
- tk=8.5.18=0
- torchvision=0.1.8=py27_0
- tornado=4.5.1=py27_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py27_0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py27_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py27_0
- zlib=1.2.8=3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352841/how-to-update-an-existing-conda-environment-with-a-yml-file Might be useful