# How to install multiple conda packages offline with correct dependency resolution, using miniconda?

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I have a versioned software which relies on several Python packages. I need to install it on infrastructure which does not have Internet access. Ideally, as my single source of truth, I would like to use an environment.yml file, but cannot figure out how to do that.

For organizational reasons, on my target machine, I only have miniconda available.

## What I have tried

Before any of the following, I have downloaded all the bz2/conda files and copied them to a folder `pkgs` on the target machine. In the same folder as the pkgs folder, I have put an environment.yml file which looks like this:

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hcfcfb64_5
  # other packages
  - pip:
      - attrs==23.1.0
      # other packages
```

I have also run `conda config --set offline True` on the target machine.

0. Creating a new environment with
   `conda env create --file environment.yml`

This fails with

```
The following packages are not available from current channels:
[...]
Current channels:
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
```

1. Creating a new environment, then downloading the actual bz2 files of the packages, copying them to the offline machine, and looping `conda install <file_name>` over the directory (as a modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48259527/11404396). For some of the packages, this fails (I assume because at that time, their dependencies are not yet met.) I would need to perform this several times, until it does not produce any errors, which seems cumbersome.
2. Creating a new environment, then putting all of the packages in a tar and passing the tar to `conda install`, which should work according to [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/packages/install-packages/#installing-packages-on-a-non-networked-air-gapped-computer):

> To install a .tar file containing many conda packages, run the following command:
>
> conda install /packages-path/packages-filename.tar

`conda install .\pkgs.tar` tries to execute the command with channel `defaults` and then fails with

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
- .\pkgs.tar
```

3. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352841/how-to-update-an-existing-conda-environment-with-a-yml-file), created an environment and executed
   `conda env update --file environment.yml --prune` in the folder where there is a pkgs folder containing the downloaded packages.

This fails with the following error:

`InvalidMatchSpec: Invalid spec 'bzip2[url=file:///C:/Users/<...>/pkgs/bzip2-1.0.8-hcfcfb64_5.conda]': Libmamba only supports a subset of the MatchSpec interface for now. You can only use ('name', 'version', 'build', 'channel', 'subdir'), but you tried to use ('url',).`

4. Tried using the same command with `--solver classic` instead of libmamba, for pip to fail due to proxy error (despite the offline mode being enabled). As a result, no packages are installed.

## Re possible question duplication

I believe this is not a duplicate of [How can I install a conda environment when offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103362/11404396), because that question does not deal with an environment.yml.

I believe this is not a duplicate of [How to update an existing Conda environment with a .yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58103362/11404396), because that question does not deal with being offline.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem a while back at work and I believe the following steps worked for me.

1. Create a new Conda environment and install all of your required packages. Conda will handle the dependencies for you.
2. Export a list of all the packages that got installed in this
   environment to a .yml file.

   `conda my_env export > env.yml`

   This should give you a .yml file with all the dependencies as well.
3. Create a new Conda environment (this is important as you don't want
   to pollute it with packages from any of your existing environments),
   activate it, and download the specified packages using the
   `--download-only` flag.

   `conda create --name download_env --env.yml --download-only`
4. Conda will download the packages and store them in its package cache
   directory. You can check the actual location of the package cache
   directory by running `conda info --envs` in your Conda environment.
   Look for the "pkgs directories" entry in the output and it will show
   you the path to the package cache directory for your current Conda
   environment.
5. Copy the downloaded packages from the Conda cache directory to your
   offline target machine.
6. On your offline machine, create a new Conda environment using the
   copied packages and the `--use-local flag`. Run this inside the
   directory where you have copied the downloaded Conda packages.

   `conda create --name new_env --use-local --file env.yml`
7. Activate the newly created environment:

   `conda activate new_env`

Answer (score 1):

## Root cause

You got errors during the anaconda installation because the machine does not have internet access, so, it means that you did not pack ALL the dependencies in the file.

The dependencies are not limited to the packages you declared in the file environment.

## Solution

You need to package your project. That is, resolve all the dependencies and put them all together in  the same file.

I suggest you those steps:

### 1. Create Environment.yml File

Create an environment.yml file that lists all the packages and their versions, as you did:

```
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - bzip2=1.0.8=hcfcfb64_5
  # other packages
  - pip:
      - attrs==23.1.0
      # other packages
```

### 2. Export Packages to Tarballs

On a machine with internet access, use the `conda pack` command to export the specified packages and their dependencies into tarballs:

```bash
conda pack -n my_environment -o my_environment.tar.gz
```

### 3.Transfer the Tarball to the offline machine

Upload the tar file with as you need.

### 4. Create the environment from Tarball

```
conda create --name my_environment --use-local --file my_environment.tar.gz
```

--use-local option tells conda to use locally available packages. In your case, it's used in conjunction with the --file option to indicate that the environment specification is provided in a local tarball file (my_environment.tar.gz).

### 5. Activate the env and test it

```
conda activate my_environment
conda list && conda info
```

## Extra Ball

I also recommend you the following official resource on conda doc for further deployments of conda environments: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/